# Rounding in C# to 2 decimal places from higher precision number

Tags: c#, rounding

How would I round the following number in C# to obtain the following results.

Value : 500.0349999999

After Rounding to 2 digits after decimal : 500.04

I have tried `Math.Round(Value,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);` //but it returns the value 500.03 instead of 500.04

Comment: What sort of rounding rules would round 500.034999 to 500.04?  If you figure that out, you can write the rounding routine yourself.

Comment: Oracle does that kind of rounding; But I could write a function to implement it. But I was just wondering if there is builtin function that could accomplish it; instead of reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for non-standard rounding rules. The value 500.03499999999 rounded to the nearest hundredth should be 500.03. Since the thousandths digit is less than 5, the hundredths digit remains unchanged.

One way I can see to achieve your desired result is to round the number to the decimal place one smaller than what you ultimately want. Then round that result to the precision you want.

In your example, you would round the value to 3 decimal places resulting in 500.035. You would then round that to 2 decimal places which should result in 500.04 (assuming you're using `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am not too sure if its non-standard. Problem I have is I am doing some internal calculation using the rounded off value before writing to the Oracle Database. When the data is submitted to Oracle as 500.03499999 which has a precision set to 17,2; it writes the data as 500.04, however in .Net I used 500.03 for calculations. I know I can write few lines of code to handle this issue. But I just wanted to know if there is some built-in code for .net framework to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it needlessly complex and wrap a variable Round(Decimal, Int32) function in a for loop. Decrement the Int32 to work it's way back to the decimal precision needed. It's a bit of work but like Eric said, you are asking for non-standard rounding rules.

Extra details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx

Comment: I am not too sure if its non-standard. Problem I have is I am doing some internal calculation using the rounded off value before writing to the Oracle Database. When the data is submitted to Oracle as 500.03499999 which has a precision set to 17,2; it writes the data as 500.04, however in .Net I used 500.03 for calculations.  I know I can write few lines of code to handle this issue. But I just wanted to know if there is some built-in code for .net framework to handle it.